# turn string into jquery snippet

Tags: jquery, string

Given some jquery code stored as a string, such as:

```
var snippet = "$('.current')";
```

How to use it as jquery code? For example this does not seem to work:

```
snippet.removeClass('current');
```

...console says

```
Uncaught TypeError: snippet.removeClass is not a function
```

Additionally passing only the selector '.current' is not acceptable, the whole jquery code should be passed.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to store jquery code stored as a string? You can just persists the selector

Comment: @Satpal the jquery code is stored as a data attribute of a clicked element which makes it a string ( I assume ). I need to retrieve it from the attribute and turn it into code as explained. I understand storing code as data attributes does not sound very reasonable, but I can't change that, and still need to find a solution. Thank you.

Comment: show the relevant code, this seems to be XY problem

Comment: `var snippet = eval("$('.current')");` Note that this is a horrible way of doing things, starting from _the jquery code is stored as a data attribute of a clicked element_

Comment: @baao I know, but I still have to solve it, and it is a question that can be answered. Is there any alternative to eval? such as turning strings into function with var fn  = window[string] , then fn() ? care to post an answer?

Comment: _“Is there any alternative to eval? such as turning strings into function with [...]”_ - that would have the same basic problems as eval. _“the jquery code is stored as a data attribute of a clicked element”_ - and where/how does this happen? Is it completely arbitrary code, or does it always follow more or less the same schema, i.e. what parts of `var snippet = "$('.current')";` would be “variable” here? The selected class only, or what actual code is executed/what variable the result is assigned to as well?

Comment: There's no such alternative and with the code you've posted it won't be possible to advise further.